# Rails Pass additional parameters in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was under the impression that it's possible to pass additional parameters within a `link_to` tag in Rails.  What I have is a button that a user can click on to move over to another controllers `show` method/view and I need to be able to pass `@network_host.id` to the new controller `issues_controller.rb`, but it's not working.  Instead, I get redirected back to my `root_url`.

In order of how the user would do it:

> 1. User navigates to www.myserver.com/network_hosts/XX (the show method)
> 2. controllers/network_hosts_controller.rb kicks in

```
class NetworkHostsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_network_host, only: [:show]

   def show
     @network_host = NetworkHost.find(params[:id])
     if @network_host
       @major_issues = get_host_issues(@network_host, @network_host.last_test, "major")
       @minor_issues = get_host_issues(@network_host, @network_host.last_test, "minor")
     end
   end
end
```

> 3. views/network_hosts/show.html.erb (User clicks the link_to button)

```
<tbody>
  <% @major_issues.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |result, index| %>
    <% issue = result.issue %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'.html_safe, issue_path({ id: issue.id, host: @network_host.id }), "data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "View" %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

> 4. Which should then fire controllers/issues_controller.rb (show method, i.e. www.myserver.com/issues/5432),

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
    @network_host = NetworkHost.find(params[:host])
  end
end
```

However, step 4 isn't working, instead it routes back to the homepage.  So in my console, I'm looking at what parameters are being passed, and I don't see the `host` parameter:

```
Started GET "/issues/54387" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-13 14:06:49 -0400
Processing by IssuesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"54387"}
```

Am I implementing this wrong?

Comment: What's in your rendered html for `views/network_hosts/show.html.erb`?

Comment: Just a bunch of `@network_host` values.  Not having an issue with any of that, just this damn link to.

Comment: More specifically, what do the rendered links look like in html? Do they get the additional param properly?

Comment: Ah, sorry, no: `<a data-toggle="tooltip" href="/issues/5" title="" data-original-title="View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>`

Comment: I think I might have just figured it out though... looks like I can't just 'make up' a parameter name as I was doing with `host`.  Instead, I have to use the modeled name:  `<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'.html_safe, issue_path({id: issue.id, network_host: @network_host.id}), "data-toggle" => "tooltip", "title" => "View" %>`  This works, but it passes the paramter in the URL, which I don't really like doing: `http://localhost:3000/issues/5?network_host=55`  Any way around it?

Comment: Well, your first approach should be working just as well, adding the extra parameter in the same fashion. The only required thing is route-declared parameters to be present. Since you'r request is `get` (as with all plain links) there is no straightforward way around that. You could either use `post` from javascript or some cookies/sessions hackery to pass the extra values. There is nothing wrong with an url like yours though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but the `host` option in your route helper (and all other derivatives of `url_for`) is reserved for modifying the host in the generated URLs. But since you're using `issue_path` and not `issue_url`, the `host` parameter is just being ignored. To fix your issue, pick another parameter name.